# How get value from one UITextField to another UITextField ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextfield

I have 2 UITextFields. one is for $ and another is for Riel. when I type in textfield$, I want to see value in textfieldRiel automatically. How to do that ?

Comment: do you want dynamic change of text.. or when textfield$ is done editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement uitextfielddelegate method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
   textFieldRiel.text = textField.text;
   return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) protocol, conform to it and make your controller class the delegate of the first ($) UITextField. Then for example in the `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method, which gets called whenever the user types a new character, populate the other UITextField according to your requirements!

Answer (score 1):

First Declare the  in your interface file.

Then implement uitextfielddelegate method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

textfieldRiel.text=string;
return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just a simple thinks you need to implement the delegates methods of the UiTextfields.

below is the code for the when type into one textfield that text also write automatically into the Riel textfield.

```
    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
           self.txtRiel.text=textField.text
           return YES;

    }
```

Also Refer this method in Apple Documentation

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

Also refer the Apple [Documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html).